# Set highlight-style from Pandoc YAML front-matter

Tags: yaml, pandoc

Is it possible to set Pandoc's highlight-style option from the YAML front matter? It can be set via the pandoc command as a flag

```
--highlight-style=kate
```

But I don't see any mention of a highlight style digging through the Pandoc LaTeX template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is an open feature request: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2925

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Rmarkdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown) :

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    highlight: zenburn
  pdf_document:
    highlight: zenburn
---
```

FYI: I use `rmarkdown`->`master` but `1.9` should suffice and `pandoc`->`master` (`2.1.3`)